# Es correcto el CRUD que he montado en hql para su uso en hibernate?

Tags: java, hibernate, hql

Buenas estoy aprendiendo hql para usarlo en hibernate y que mejor forma que hacer un CRUD en el controlador.

A continuacion dejo el codigo :

```
 import java.io.Console;

import org.hibernate.HibernateException;
import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.Transaction;

import jdk.nashorn.internal.ir.annotations.Ignore;
import tablas.Empleados;
import utils.HibernateUtils;

public class Prueba {
    private static Session session;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // abrimos la sesion con Hibernate
        session = HibernateUtils.getSessionFactory().openSession();
        Transaction tx = session.beginTransaction();

        // creamos empleado
        Empleados empleado_nuevo = new Empleados("12345678A", "Nombre", "Apellido 1", "Apellido 2", "Rol profesional");
        /// createEmployee(empleado_nuevo);

        // borramos empleado
        ///deleteEmployee(7);

        //obtenemos empleado
        ///Empleados empleado_obtenido = getEmployee(3);
        ///empleado_obtenido.print();

        //updating empleado


        updateEmployee(5, "66666666Z", "Nombre Actualizado", "Apel 1 Actualizado", "Apel 2 Actualizado", "Programador Senior 5+ años exp");

        tx.commit();

        session.close();

        System.exit(0);

    }

    public static void createEmployee(Empleados empleado_nuevo) {
        session.save(empleado_nuevo);
        //session.flush();
    }

    public static void deleteEmployee(int id) {
        try {
            Empleados empleado_existente = getEmployee(id);

            session.delete(empleado_existente);

        } catch (HibernateException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            session.getTransaction().rollback();
        }

    }

    public static Empleados  getEmployee(int id) {
        Empleados empleado_recibido = session.get(Empleados.class, id);

        return empleado_recibido;

    }

    public static void updateEmployee(int emp_id_objetivo, String dni, String nombre, String apel_1, String apel_2,
            String roll) {


        Empleados emp_desactualizado = getEmployee(emp_id_objetivo);
        if (dni != null) {
            emp_desactualizado.setEmpDni(dni);  
        }
        if (nombre != null) {
            emp_desactualizado.setEmpNombre(nombre);
        }
        if (apel_1 != null) {
            emp_desactualizado.setEmpApel1(apel_1); 
        }
        if (apel_2 != null) {
            emp_desactualizado.setEmpApel2(apel_2);
        }
        if (roll != null) {
            emp_desactualizado.setEmpRol(roll); 
        }

        session.saveOrUpdate(emp_desactualizado);

    }

}
```

Otra duda que no acabo de entender es el uso de **commit()** y **flush()**
 . Se que tienen que ver con el correcto guardado de los datos en la base de datos pero no los comprendo mas alla de eso.

Comment: El commit es necesario para que se apliquen los cambios en la base de datos. Si tienes configurado la conexión con el autoCommit a true no te hará falta.  Tu puedes aplicar cambios (guardar, eliminar,actualizar) de todo tipo de objetos, pero si no haces un commit, estos no se reflejaran en la base de datos. El flush no estoy seguro al 100% pero creo que era para forzar el vaciado del buffer de la conexión para asegurarte que la información ha llegado a la base de datos.

Comment: ¿Y donde está aquí el HQL? Estás usando Hibernate, pero no HQL